# Identify when the app crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c

Likewise  that have functions in Objective-C to know when the screen will Appear, or When the User exit the app, or receive memory warning, I believe there is a way to know when the device will give crash.

If this function exists, I could create an alert will notify the user that the application has an error and the logs would be sent to my email, I wonder if this Possibility exists?.

Grateful.

Comment: Well this would go against the idea of a crash. Would the crashed/crashing program be the one sending you an email notification?

Comment: Let's imagine that your application is in the app store and suddenly the User reported that the application closed alone, in this case something went unnoticed by the developer, in this case if exists this possibility we could show a message to User, in addition to be able to post logs with errors for email programmer

Comment: @PaulG works like a 'try' and 'catch' commands, but this inside the app delegate, this function exists? would not be a bad idea developers of the Objective-C language to implement it in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like every POSIX process, iOS apps receive signals when they're crashing. thats how test flight works.

a) for exceptions use the function `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler`

b) for a signal handler (other crashes then exception) use `signal`

I won't write all the code here but for further info Ill refer to:
http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/05/handling-unhandled-exceptions-and.html

BUT

I would just try to avoid crashing because a handler often isn't really useful and it can very well be tricky to implement a signal handler because everything CAN be in a corrupt state. For example it may well corrupt your CoreData database or user defaults.

Don't ship it I'd say :)